# How much time does it take to install iOS7 Beta 4 on iPhone5 (A1428 model)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, iphone-5

I downloaded the .ipsw file for iOS 7 Beta 4 from Apple's developer website and started installing it using iTunes. iTunes completed its operation and gave message that iPhone will restart automatically once installation complete. I've been waiting for almost 1 and half hour and the progress bar on iPhone is still at the beginning.

Does anybody has any idea about how much time it takes to install? Is anything going wrong. Please advise. 
Status:-

[image: http://i.imgur.com/il2PKnz.jpg]

Comment: I had similar issue upgrading a 6.1 device to beta 4, but the OTA update on a device running 7.0 beta 3 to beta 4 was fine. Regardless, I'd suggest directing your inquiry to http://devforums.apple.com, where people will be more free to discuss issues otherwise covered by the NDA.

Comment: Devforums are still down :(

Comment: it took about 20-25 mins, including everything but download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it doesn't take that long. I installed it, and it took around 15 mins. Did you try re-installing it? Try downloading the new ios 7 developer version, it is less buggy, and your problem may have been fixed. Also try reffering to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6YSmgxpbmo&noredirect=1 Just give it another try. Wait, is your Iphone jailbroken?

Comment: No, not Jailbroken. But my iPhone is 64 GB and has lot of Apps. So, this is the current status.

![Screenshot][1]

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/il2PKnz.jpg

Comment: That happened to me to the first time. So what has happened is that your phone is stuck on the loading menu. This normally happens when you have a lot of apps, and what not. Is this beta 2 or 3? Because beta 2 has a bug in the loading screen, which is what you seem to have.

Comment: I am trying to Install Beta 4. So, now how can I restart the installation. DO I need to hard reboot?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you must perform hard reboot. Once that is done, your phone should be reverted back to before. Please tell me if it works.

Comment: well, we can always try both. If the hard reboot doesn't work, your next option would be to, like Rob says, put it into recovery mode, and restore the device from a backup. But the hard reboot should work, unless you deleted your previous firmware before you downloaded ios 7.

Comment: Hmm... Hard reboot didn't work. So I am trying the recovery mode now.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply, recovery mode should work. Do you know how to perform the process of restoring your phone to backup?

Comment: I started the recovery mode by connecting to the iTunes and restored it from the backup. Shall I try installing the iOS7 Beta 4 again or do I need to do anything before that?

Comment: Well, once it is done, delete some of your apps, then I would recommend downloading beta 3, because beta 4 will crash your iphone 5. http://www.phonesreview.co.uk/2013/08/04/ios-7-beta-4-fixes-iphone-4s-5-crashing/

Comment: Thanks Hetesh and Rob. I was able to install iOS 7 Beta 3 successfully. Looks like there is some problem with Beta 4 build.

Comment: No problem:) yeah, apple still has to fix  beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

On my iPhone 5, and based on your tags it took less than 15 minutes. There may be a problem with Apple's Server verifying the ipsw, unless this has already been done. Do you have lots of apps in the cloud? that could effect the time as well≥ 1 1/2 hours is unusually long for that to install.